# Updating Values of Dataframe Column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update a column in my pandas dataframe but cannot figure out how to do it. I think I need to use `.update`, but I am not sure how.

My current dataframe looks like this (called `auto_df`):

| id | Make | Make (Encoded) | Model | Model (Encoded) | Score | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | Kia | 14 | Forte Lx | 103 | 0.0 | 15000 |
| 106 | Nissan | 21 | Sentra S | 181 | 0.0 | 14998 |
| 107 | Toyota | 26 | Avalon Xl | 22 | 0.0 | 14995 |
| 108 | Chevrolet | 4 | Camaro Lt | 34 | 0.0 | 14995 |
| 109 | Kia | 14 | Sportage Lx | 204 | 0.0 | 14995 |

I have another dataframe with updated score values (called `auto_df_non`), and I want to replace the 0 values in this dataframe with the updated score values.

`auto_df_non` looks like this:

| id | Make | Make (Encoded) | Model | Model (Encoded) | Score | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 105 | Kia | 14 | Forte Lx | 103 | 44.439907 | 15000 |
| 106 | Nissan | 21 | Sentra S | 181 | 27.530042 | 14998 |
| 107 | Toyota | 26 | Avalon Xl | 22 | 56.666503 | 14995 |
| 108 | Chevrolet | 4 | Camaro Lt | 34 | 16.844859 | 14995 |
| 109 | Kia | 14 | Sportage Lx | 204 | 14.013014 | 14995 |

I have tried to get `.update` to work, but everything I have found on the internet so far has not been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

we need minimal and reproducible example for answer. lets make

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 0, 'c'], ['b', 0, 'd']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 10, 'e'], ['b', 20, 'f']], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col4'])
```

`df1`

```
   col1 col2    col3
0   a   0       c
1   b   0       d
```

`df2`

```
   col1 col2    col4
0   a   10      e
1   b   20      f
```

---

**Code**

```
df1.update(df2)
```

`df1`

```
  col1  col2    col3
0   a   10      c
1   b   20      d
```